# Convert to Web Application in VS 2015.1

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, visual-studio-2015

I'm running Visual Studio 2015 Enterprise Update 1.

I created an empty Visual Basic ASP.NET Website targeting the .NET Framework 4.5.2. And I want to convert it to an ASP.NET Web Application.

Under the Website's context menu in Solution Explorer there is no "Convert to Web Application" menu-item, nor is there anything under the Website menu in the main-menu bar:

[image]

[image]

Where has the feature gone? Has it been removed completely in Update 1?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

This is the most confusing part of converting websites to web applications.  The way you need to do it is to:

1. Create a new Web Application project
2. Copy all of your website contents into it (you could create the *.csproj file in the same website directory, then include all files into the project without actually having to move them)
3. The command will be available on the WebApp project (under the Project menu, at the bottom)

Basically at that point the command looks at the contents of the WebApp project and makes adjustments so that they are more suitable for a WebApp project.

Comment: I ran the command on a rather large (and poorly designed) VB.NET Website Project - it introduced a lot of build errors caused by pages in different directories using the same code-behind class name without namespaces (e.g. `Foo/Index.aspx.vb` and `Bar/Index.aspx.vb` - both called `Partial Public Class Index`). I'm surprised it doesn't correct this automatically.

Comment: @Dai where you able to convert it?

Comment: @MarcoAlves Yes I was able to - that's why I posted this answer.

Comment: @Dai thank you for your response. I asked it because I have a large project file (hundreds of .aspx and .ascx) and don't have a clue about how many errors may happen and how complex it could be.

Comment: Another common problem is people adding assemblies to the ~/bin folder in the website. When migrating to a WAP I usually move these to a ~/libs folder and add a reference to them there. That allows you to still ignore your bin folder in source control but still have the assemblies added in, plus it makes your assembly-adding more explicit so you'll remember to do it. Obviously using NuGet and/or Bower is a better option for newer sites, but I maintain a lot of old sites I don't have time to update.

Comment: Just to make it absolutely clear to future readers, this option is only available on the top-level Visual Studio Project menu on the VS menu bar when a web application is selected in Solution Explorer. I never use the VS menu bar for this sort of thing. I was hunting around in the right-click context menu. It is no longer available in the context menu.